# Workflow rule formula help - Two picklist values cannot be populated together

Tags: workflow, formula

I'm trying to create a workflow rule that fires when:

1. Status = New
2. Type = Incident
3. Origin is not Production Monitoring or Proactive outreach
   AND
4. Does not have BOTH of these picklist values
   A. Origin = Web Inquiry
   B. Category = Change Form

The way it is written right now, if it has either of #4's picklist values it is not firing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL( Status, "New"),
    ISPICKVAL(Type, "Incident"),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL (Origin, "Production Monitoring")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL (Origin, "Proactive Outreach")),
    AND(
        NOT(ISPICKVAL(Origin, "Web Inquiry")),
        NOT(ISPICKVAL(Category__c, "Change Form"))
    )
)
```

Comment: I would avoid using `&&` and `!` in your formulas and instead use `AND` and `NOT` respectively. That will make them more readable imho.

Comment: Okay, how about this?  `code` AND(ISPICKVAL( Status, "New"), ISPICKVAL(Type, "Incident"), NOT(ISPICKVAL (Origin, "Production Monitoring")), NOT(ISPICKVAL (Origin, "Proactive Outreach")),
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Origin, "Web Inquiry")), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Category__c, "Change Form"))))`code`

Comment: It is better to make edits to your post than dump code in comments. It looks like you got it though. I edited your post for you.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It's treating the second AND as an either or.  If I create a case with an origin of "Web Inquiry' it isn't firing. I only want it to not fire if the origin is 'Web Inquiry' and the Category is 'Change Form'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to invert your `NOT` and `AND` in the final clause:

```
NOT(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Origin, "Web Inquiry"),
        ISPICKVAL(Category__c, "Change Form")
    )
)
```